Get Object CLOB of Oracle
I have a SQL query with different parameters that returns a HUGECLOB object and I would like to know how I can obtain said object so I can save it on the computer, paint it or capture it. The HUGECLOB object contains an XML file version 1.0 and encoded ISO-8859-1. How can I create that microservice to obtain the object that the query returns? or how can I convert the hugeclob to string?
The query is :
SELECT package.function(:param1, :param2, :param3) CLOB FROM DUAL


I just want to get some response from the database that it was done correctly. That's quite unclear. You should expand upon it. And, presumably, since it's a clob, it's large. So are you sure you want to load it all into memory?

We need to understand what you are asking ... if you want us to answer you.  Please clarify your question.   In addition to g00se's questions, what exactly do you expect to happen when you cast a string to a list of some class?  How?

The other calls I have made in Java Spring have this structure and since I don't know how to adapt it, I tried that; When the query is performed in Oralce, a HUGECLOB is obtained with a fairly large xml and my question is, how can I make the call with different parameters and obtain the object that the query returns?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Another little question - why are you removing the first character, and, anticipating your answer, what encoding does the contained xml have?

The substring is any example I got from Google, and the XML is version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"

I'm going to rephrase the question.

You need something like while (rs.next()) {try (Reader in = rs.getCharacterStream(1)){in.transferTo(Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "clob.xml")));}}

Thanks, I finally got it with:  rs =dataSource.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(query.toString());             while (rs.next()) {                 clob = (CLOB) rs.getObject(1);                 stringXml = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());             }       but it returns it as a string and I have to parse it to xml, and that would be my next question, how can I parse a string to xml?

That would depend on what you were going to do with the xml. What are you intending? You're doing that substringing thing again - why?

because it works like that, but thanks, you gave me some clue and it was what I needed
